# Having a user click a link in a Slack Incoming Webhook Message and getting their response

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm looking to have a user type something like

```
/makemeeting today @ 4:00pm
```

this fires a outgoing webhook, which stores the info, then it fires a incoming webhook which would display a message in a channel saying meeting scheduled, and have two links

```
yes | no
```

Here's where I'm stuck. I can do everything up till this point. I'd love for any user to be able to click on one of those links and have it perform another outgoing webhook with the proper response.

I know I can just make those links point to a website, but I'd love to keep it all within slack without having to open a browser.

Is this possible? I swear I've seen yes|no, true|false replies before in other commands and bots, but I might be imagining that.

Any help would be appreciated...
thanks

Comment: I believe this is impossible but something Slack has mentioned as being on their roadmap.

Comment: I think you are right. The closest idea I can come up with is having it post a /joinmeeting [id] comment that they can copy that's also a link to the page...

Comment: Yes, @smarx is right. Buttons are on their near term roadmap.

Comment: I am trying to do EXACTLY the same kind of task in a custom integration I'm working on. Glad I'm not the only one struggling to figure this out, and that it's at least on the roadmap. This feature will open up vastly more powerful Slack integrations and can't come soon enough

Comment: @RexRemus - I started to look into BOTs, which can handle this sort of thing, but then the back end seems to get way out of hand quickly.

Comment: @Chenzo yeah, it seems to me that their interactive messages road map item is going to be the best/simplest option to achieve this. It just needs to get here - soon

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported yet but is on Slack's roadmap for the "near term". 
https://trello.com/c/DVrJLbxX/12-interactive-messages

A work around is to add reactions to your message. When the user clicks the reaction (to bump up its count), an RTM event will be dispatched for you to handle:  https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added

An live example can be seen with the Meekan calendar app:  https://meekan.com/slack/

So you could have two reactions: thumbs up and a thumbs down. And handle which reaction the user clicked.

Comment: Interactive buttons are now live in the Slack API, though they require an app and don't work with custom integrations (yet)